# Why yarn creates a .pnp.loader.mjs and .pnp.cjs files

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I use vite on react, and when i use yarn to "live server" my project two new files are created, .pnp.loader.mjs and .pnp.cjs. What is the purpose of this files?
I never see those files, always use npm or yarn and is the first time that they appear.

[image: files]

Comment: Any update on this one?

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp

Comment: The doc doesn't mention the .pnp.loader.mjs.

Answer (score 8):

The `.pnp.cjs` is part of the Yarn [Plug'n'Play](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp/#initializing-pnp) process, which makes our install and runtime much faster.  It makes the `node_modules` obsolete.

Yarn also creates an experimental ESM loader which is called `.pnp.loader.mjs`.

Comment: The doc doesn't mention the .pnp.loader.mjs.

Comment: So I assume that we also commit `.php.loader.mjs` to git along with `.pnp.cjs` right?

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-next-app@latest
npx next dev
```

The issue is from Yarn @Jan Willems says

Comment: any links for the disucssion?

Comment: I use the official documentation and instead to follow the Yarn setup, I’m following the NPM setup